# iOS Swift 4 Printing

Tags: ios, swift, printing

I am trying to print an image that is 1280x960 on a 4x6 and I can't figure out how to get it to shrink to fit. Code I am using is below. I know the image can't fit perfect and that is not what I am after, I just want it to shrink to fit.

```
let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    printInfo.outputType = .photo
    if isLandscape(){
        printInfo.orientation = .landscape
    } else {
        printInfo.orientation = .portrait
    }
    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    printController.printInfo = printInfo
    printController.printingItem = self.shareableImage.image
    printController.showsNumberOfCopies = false
    printController.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers = true
    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You say you are `trying to print an image` and that your code `just printing an image`.

Comment: @Magnas The image is printing fine, I am trying to get the image to shrink to fit, instead its printing and a lot of the image is getting cut off.